# Unable to pass multiple values in the where clause of a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a LINQ query something like below:

```
var results=from p in inputTable.AsEnumerable()
          where inputParameter.Contains(p.Field<String>(inputField))&&
                p.Field<string>(CurrencyCode)==currencyCode
          group p by new
          {
           p[CurrencyCode],
          } into groupedTable
          select new
          {
           Amount = groupedTable.Sum(r => r.Field<System.Decimal>(amountField))
          };
if (results.Count() > 0)
            {
                retVal = results.ElementAt(0).Amount;
            }
```

My `inputParameter` is basically a `List<string>` which will have values like `{October, November, December}`.

The `inputField` is `November`.

My thought is that since the where condition has a Contains method it will just filter rows by `November`, since `inputField` is `November`.

I basically need to pass all the elements of the list, i.e. `October`, `November` and `December` and then get records filtered by these months.

I tried to use `where-in` stuff of `LINQ` but was not successful.

Experts please help to crack this question.
Any help/pointer will be highly appreciable.

**EDIT:**

Let me try to make this question very simple.

My `List<string>` `inputParameter` can contain variable strings, like `{October, November, December}` or `{January, February, March, April}` and so on.

I need my query to pass in all these values and filter the records accordingly.

The simplified query which I tried is follows:

```
var results=from p in inputTable.AsEnumerable()
            where p.Field<string>(FiscalMonth)==inputParameter[0] ||
                  p.Field<string>(FiscalMonth)==inputParameter[1] ||
                  p.Field<string>(FiscalMonth)==inputParameter[2]
            select new
                {
                 p.Amount
                 };
```

In the above instance I have basically hardcoded the individual elements of the List `inputParameter`, but my list will be variable at times. i.e it may hold 3 items, 4 items, or even 12 items.

How to mould the above query to avoid individual hard-coding?

Regards

Anurag

Comment: What doesn't work? Your code seems to handle List<string> as it's supposed to.

Comment: Mr. Marko, I need to pass the whole string in the where clause, i.e I need to get results for Oct, Nov, Dec. Currently the above query gives me results only for November, which is passed as inputField parameter.

Comment: If you set your `inputParamter` to `new List<string>() {"October", "November", "December"}` your code should work fine. `inputField` is a name of a column in `inputTable`, not a filter field.

Comment: Yah a strange name for a column in a table as well, I'd have been expecting ????_Month or some such.

Comment: Tony: inputField is basically passed as a parameter to the function in which this LINQ query is written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to your edit, it should be :

```
var results = from p in inputTable.AsEnumerable()
              where inputParameter.Contains(p.Field<string>(FiscalMonth))
              select new
                {
                    p.Amount
                };
```

This is a working console example that demonstrate query with `Contains` :

```
//create datatable with column FiscalMonth
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("FiscalMonth");

//add two rows, January and October
var row1 = table.NewRow();
row1["FiscalMonth"] = "January";
var row2 = table.NewRow();
row2["FiscalMonth"] = "October";
table.Rows.Add(row1);
table.Rows.Add(row2);

//query from data table where FiscalMonth in (October, November, December)
var inputParameter = new List<string> {"October", "November", "December"};
var result = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
             where inputParameter.Contains(r.Field<string>("FiscalMonth"))
             select r.Field<string>("FiscalMonth");

//the result will be only one row, which is October. January is successfully filtered out
foreach (var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Comment: I am currently debugging with the above query which you have written...will let you know the result.

Comment: I'm not sure about this part `p.Amount`. If you find exception at that part, try something like `Amount = p.Field<System.Decimal>(Amount)` instead, with `Amount` is column name in your DataTable, and `System.Decimal` is data type of that column.

Comment: p.Amount part is fine. But I am not getting the correct results Mr. har07. Even if inputparameter is {October, November} or {October, November, December}, I am getting the same result. What do you say? If I need to filter a column with multiple values like (select * from dbo.Table where ID in (1,2,3)), it gives me records for which ID is 1,2 or 3. Same thing I want here, but with LINQ. The Contains method doesn't give desired result. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I will suggest to check your data instead. I tested it in console project, and the query worked as expected

Comment: Yes..Mr har07..my input table has only November, hence it gives me results for only November month, whatever List I pass. Some data ambiguity..Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Doesn't matter. And don't forget to accept the answer to confirm your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Do not really understand exactly what you are looking for, since you are stating that you want to query on only Month and your code is querying on month and currency code.  but looks like you are returning the sum of the Amount. So he is a first stab at what you want to do.

```
class MonthCurrency
    {
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public int CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    }
    static List<MonthCurrency> inputTable  = null;

    static void Main(string[] args){
        inputTable = new List<MonthCurrency>()
        {     new MonthCurrency() { Month = "October", CurrencyCode= 1, Amount = 1},
              new MonthCurrency() { Month = "October", CurrencyCode= 1, Amount = 2},
              new MonthCurrency() { Month = "November", CurrencyCode= 2, Amount = 1},
              new MonthCurrency() { Month = "November", CurrencyCode= 2, Amount = 2},
              new MonthCurrency() { Month = "December", CurrencyCode= 3, Amount = 1},
              new MonthCurrency() { Month = "December", CurrencyCode= 3, Amount = 2},
        };   
        var result = GetCurrencyCode("November");
    }

    static public decimal GetCurrencyCode(string inputParameter)
    {
        decimal retVal = 0.0M;
        var results = from p in inputTable.AsEnumerable()
                      where p.Month == inputParameter
                      group p by new
                      {
                          p.CurrencyCode,
                      } into groupedTable
                      select new MonthCurrency
                      {                              
                          Amount = groupedTable.Sum(r => r.Amount)
                      };
        if (results.Count() > 0)
        {
            retVal = results.ElementAt(0).Amount;
        }
        return retVal;
    }
```

Hopefully this will help you out

Comment: I get your point Mr. Lawrence. Can you tell me how will I pass the whole List in the where clause of the LINQ query?

Comment: what do you mean by the whole list? like you want everything returned from your data?